# How to extract a "ComputedProperty" to it's real value?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to implement amCharts into a project, and it looks like when I pass it the EmberData model as it's dataProvider, it can't understand the promises.

I've tried to fix this by creating a computed property in my controller that looks like:

Route:

```
--route.js
import Ember from 'ember';

const {Route, RSVP} = Ember;

export default Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
        start: {refreshModel: true},
        stop:  {refreshModel: true}
    },

    model(params) {

        let filter = {
            filter: {
                start: params.start,
                stop:  params.stop
            }
        };

        return RSVP.hash({
            users: this.store.query('userActivity', filter, {async: false}),
        });
    },

    setupController(controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
        controller.set('users', model.users);
    },
});
```

Controller (there are other parts I've stripped out, but they aren't relevant, suffice to say they just change the query params which triggers a model refresh from route):

```
--controller.js
import Ember from 'ember';
const {Controller, computed, get, set} = Ember;

export default Controller.extend({
  queryParams: [ 'start', 'stop' ],

  dataProvider: computed('users', function () {
    let users = get(this, 'users')
        .map(function (user) {
            return {
                calls_out:    user.calls_out,
                calls_in:     user.calls_in,
            }
        });
    console.log(users);
    return users;
  }),

});
```

However, when I log this I get the following:

```
0: Object +
    calls_in: ComputedProperty
    calls_out: ComputedProperty
    __proto__: Object
1: Object
2: Object
```

which means the object that amCharts needs to work with is still not the raw data. Is there a way to extract the data out into numbers rather than a `Promise` or a `ComputedProperty`?

Thanks!

Edit - adding `userActivity` model as requested:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    // Attributes
    title:                    DS.attr('string'),
    first_name:               DS.attr('string'),
    last_name:                DS.attr('string'),
    calls_in:           DS.attr('number'),
    calls_out:          DS.attr('number'),

    // Computed Attributes
    full_name: Ember.computed('first_name', 'last_name', function () {
        return `${this.get('first_name')} ${this.get('last_name')}`;
    }),

    // Relationships
    user: DS.belongsTo('user')

});
```

Comment: may you please write more of your codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every attribute on a `DS.Model` is defined with `DS.attr()` and will be a Computed Property. This is required so that ember-data ca track changes and rollback or update attributes.

For your use case best is to use `getProperties`:

```
const {computed,get,getProperties} = Ember;
...
dataProvider: computed('users.@each.calls_out', 'users.@each.calls_in', function () {
  return get(this, 'users').map(u => getProperties(u, 'calls_out', 'calls_in'));
})
```

Then get(this, 'dataProvider') will give you a raw Javascript Array with raw Javascript Objects with raw strings (or numbers, depending on your `DS.attr`).

Comment: and if you don't know the name of parameter of value then ?

Answer (score 0):

What is in the "user" class? Are they Ember object? You may provide more code.

If "calls_in" and "calls_out" are computed properties of this user class, you should call them like this:

```
    let users = get(this, 'users')
    .map(function (user) {
        return {
            calls_out:    user.get('calls_out'),
            calls_in:     user.get('calls_in'),
        }
    });
```

Comment: The `user` property is just mapped from the `route.js` file and relates to `userActivity`, I have included the model code. The only computed property in the model is `full_name`

Comment: Ok, did you try _user.get('calls_out')_ ?